# Dynamically create list with function

Tags: haskell

My goal is to create an infinite list by applying a function to the last element. For example if I begin with a list that looks like

```
[1]
```

and apply the function f(x) = (x + 2) * 10, I should end with

```
[1, 30, 320, 3220, 32220...]
```

How would I code this in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate):

```
Prelude> let f x = (x + 2) * 10 in take 5 $ iterate f 1
[1,30,320,3220,32220]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's `iterate`

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a] -- Repeat a function forever, making a list of values
```

If you want to start with a list and only operate on its last element:

```
func f xs = (init xs) ++ (iterate f $ last xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already got your answer: you use `iterate`. Here's how you can code it yourself.

`iterate` takes a function `f` and a *seed* `x`, and repeats function application forever (i.e. returns `[x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x)), ...]`)

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x = x : map f (iterate f x)
```

Comment: How about `iterate f (f x)` instead of `map f (iterate f x)`?

Comment: @Ryan Yours is a better implementation, and indeed the one that GHC uses.

Comment: `iterate f x = ys where ys = x : map f ys` should be better.

Comment: @Ryan you are right, it is better implementation-wise, but putting it this way, or even Will's way it's more clear that there's a fix point going around.